# There has been an internal system error within the web service

Tags: web-services

I am attempting to replace an old web service that is going away with an updated one, however whenever I call the function I want to  use, it is caught with the exception message "There has been an internal system error within the web service"
Is this possibly because of data I'm sending it or is this an issue with the web service itself? Out is there even a way to tell?

Comment: The only way to find out is if the web-service tells you .. or you figure out what the issue is (if it's under your control attach a remote debugger or view relevant logs). Read the API again, search for and reproduce examples (until finding the "breaking point") and, failing everything else, contact the developer(s).

Comment: That being said, I think that most generic "internal system" errors are from a sloppy service stack - developers like to know *what* broke, and how.

Comment: I tried a couple of other functions from the web service and they give the same unfortunate cryptic error.  However when I follow the URL, I can navigate to the web service fine, which I I'm told usually means the web service is running ok. I'm not sure if that's actually true. I think I'm going to have to end up contacting the developers. Fortunately they offered contact information to help anyone having issues upgrading to the new service